Example of unbounded, strictly increasing, strictly concave real-valued function on the real line
Is there a strictly increasing and strictly concave real-valued function defined over the entire real line?
I am looking for a real-valued function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the following properties:

Strictly increasing: $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ for all $x_1 < x_2$.

Strictly concave:
$$f(\lambda x_1 + (1 - \lambda) x_2) > \lambda f(x_1) + (1 - \lambda) f(x_2)$$
for all distinct $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \in (0, 1)$.

unbounded i.e. for $x \to \infty$, also $f(x) \to \infty$.


In other words, I’m searching for a function that is strictly increasing and strictly concave across the entire real line $\mathbb{R}$, with no domain restrictions (i.e., the function should be well-defined for all real numbers, both positive and negative).
To clarify the context:

The square root function $\sqrt{x}$ is strictly increasing and strictly concave but is not defined for negative real numbers.
The function $f(x) = -1/x$ is strictly increasing and strictly concave for $x > 0$ but fails these properties for $x < 0$.
The function $f(x) = -\exp(-x)$ is well-defined, strictly increasing, and strictly concave for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but it is bounded as $x \to \infty$.

Is there any function that meets all the criteria of being strictly increasing, strictly concave, and defined over the entire real line, while remaining unbounded? If no such function exists, I would appreciate a brief explanation of why that is the case.
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Just alter your third example to:
$$f(x) = x - \exp(-x)$$

These functions are quite common, and it’s not hard to imagine graphs of such things. It just so happens that no “common” function that’s only a single term will work, and you need to sum two together, that’s all.

For an algebraic example, consider a hyperbola, such as the $y<x$ branch of $(2x-y)(x-2y)=1.$
